# In what situations does the difference between random numbers generated on [0,1) and those generated on [0,1] make a difference?

Tags: algorithm, random, stochastic

I'm used to pseudo random number generators that return floating point values in the half open interval [0,1).

I've seen some reference to RNGs that can return values on the closed interval [0,1], e.g. [this implementation of the Mersenne Twister](http://www.bedaux.net/mtrand/mtrand.h.html).

I can see reasons why you'd want to exclude one, or both, of the endpoints for mathematical reasons, e.g.

`exponentially_distributed=-logf( 1.0-rng() )`

always yields a valid number if `0.0<=rng()<1.0`.

But I can't think of a case where replacing an rng yielding [0,1] with one that yields [0,1) would produce any practical difference.

In what situations does having a floating point pseudo random number generator
that returns values on the closed interval [0,1] absolutely necessary?

Comment: I don't think there is. It can matter when flooring, though, due to the limited precision of floating point types.

Comment: +1 Great question. I also wonder why RNGs are often on the half-open interval. It's not like you can just generate random bits for a fixed-point number, so how do they get the uniformity on a floating-point number?

Comment: I think your question may have more to do with the implementation of generating a random double than the use of it. Maybe it would be good to broaden the question to include both generation and use cases.

Comment: @AndrewMao: you get uniformity on a floating point number in the range [0,1.0) by generating integers in the range [0,2^b) and then floating-point dividing by 2^b. b, here, is the number of mantissa bits in the floating point representation. You can't generate a random floating-point representation, because that would be biased (of all the positive floating point numbers in the range [0,1.0) in IEEE749 double format, less than one in five hundred is in the range [0.5, 1.0) )

Comment: Of course you can't generate a random floating-point representation using just bits. However, there might be a clever algorithm to generate uniformly-distributed floats by recursively doing something using probabilities. However, how do you get the closed interval [0, 1] then? It must not be using integer division since you would need to generate from `[0, 2^b]` and divide by `2^b+1`.

Comment: @AndrewMao: You generate a random integer in `[0, 2^b)` and floating point divide by `2^b - 1`. (iirc, the mersenne implementation multiplies by the precomputed constant `1.0/(2^b - 1)` on the assumption that multiplication is faster than division).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe if you're randomly generating the probability of an event occurring? If you allow 0, you have to allow 1.

Answer (score 1):

Can't, figure out when the closed interval would be useful, but the open end interval seems the only reasonable to use way to go.

Lets take coin tossing:

If you say `rnd() < 0.5` is head and the rest is tail you will get more tails than heads if you use the closed interval. How many more tails depends on how likely it is to actually get 1.

Answer (score 0):

A compelling reason to use a half-open interval is the use case where you are picking a random array index for some array.  When you scale from [0, 1) to integers in [0, arrayLength], it's helpful never to get the value arrayLength, since that is not an index in the array in many language implementations.  E.g., Java and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  The half-open interval is a great convenience here.

A reason for having a closed interval [0, 1] is Albin's probability argument.  But it's worth noting that mathematically speaking, the probability of picking any particular random number, including 1, in [0, 1], is zero.  For pseudo random number generators, though, it will pop up occasionally.

Comment: Those are integers, not floating-point numbers. HUGE difference there. Specifying endpoints for integer generation is just a semantic difference. Also, probability of picking any particular float is NOT 0, and moreover it can't be just uniform over all possible floats if you want uniform distribution over [0,1].

Comment: "For pseudo random number generators, though, it will pop up occasionally." - This is not the effect of it being pseudo-random, but rather of it being finite-precision.  There are a finite number of floats on that range, but an infinite number of real numbers.